# A good open source web crawler for indexing Specific website for specific contents?

Tags: java, php, c++, web-crawler

Please suggest me a good open source web crawler written in C++,JAVA or PHP.

i just need to crawl/index some specific websites for specific contents(images,text,videos).

i know that their are already a lot of question & answers about this topic on this website

but i am a little confused after reading all of them.

So i am sorry if i am repeating the same question again.

-Thanks in advance

Comment: You're asking for a specific web crawler for a specific website but not giving us any hints to what's on the website and what you want to "scrape". We can't really help you...

Comment: That said, I suggest you look into cURL for PHP or C++.

Comment: [GNU wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/)

Comment: @Savetheinternet for example i want to index the contents of www.techcrunch.com ,here contents means text,photos and videos .

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of website. If it is required of you to log in (or a similar action) before having the ability to view/download what you want, I suggest you use [`cURL`](http://curl.haxx.se/) (preferably in [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)). Otherwise, you could use something as simple as [`wget`](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/), with sh, or [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) in PHP.

You should use some sort of HTML parser and/or regex to find specific content, depending on the site you're scraping.

Comment: for example i want to index the contents of www.techcrunch.com ,here contents means text,photos and videos .